# Chrome bookmarks - can I always choose another folder?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks

Is there a way to have Chrome always show me the entire list of bookmark folders, instead of having to navigate through the shortlist and "Choose another folder"?

[image: Screenshot - whyyyyyy?!]

I have multiple nested folders, many with similar or identical names (e.g. a "To Read" folder nested inside a given topic), and often can't tell which folder is the correct one. Showing the hierarchy inline would be impractical, so the full view is most useful to me.

Clearly I could make (and maintain) my own fork of Webkit/Chrome, switch to a 3rd-party bookmark manager extension that hijacks the keyboard shortcut for bookmarks, restructure my bookmarks, etc, but I am not really interested in approaches that are going to require more work than they save. I'm looking for a hidden setting or a "tweaks" extension (if Chrome API even allows such a thing).

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Bookmark Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-manager/gmlllbghnfkpflemihljekbapjopfjik) extension by Google. It might help you get around the issue of getting to the right folder.

When you try and save a bookmark, you'll see your nested folders by following the `>` icon.

[image: Reveal Nested Folders]